# Why this C program is not executing properly?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x,y;
    unsigned char operator;
    printf("Enter two numbers and one operater \n"); 
    scanf("%d %d %c ",&x,&y,&operator); // check " and commas
    printf("Output  ");
    switch(operator)
    {
        case '+':printf("%d",x+y); // dont jst copy paste read and paste
        break;

        case '-':printf("%d",x-y);
        break;

        case '*':printf("%d",x*y);
        break;

        case '/':printf("%d",x/y);
        break;

        default: printf("invalid operator");

    }
return 0;
}
```

After execution i entered two numbers 5 , 10 and one operator + . But i didn't get any output. But after i enter any other value i got output.
Example:

```
Enter two numbers and one operater 
40 20
+
10
Output 60
```

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %c ",&x,&y,&operator); ` -> check return value.

Comment: Tricky but change `"%d %d %c "` to `"%d %d %c"` its enough. ;)

Comment: by removing whitespace  in scanf() i got correct output.

Comment: As already commented, [consider accepting the anser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happening because of your `scanf("%d %d %c ",&x,&y,&operator);` statement, just remove space after `%c`. Use it as `scanf("%d %d %c",&x,&y,&operator);`

Resone is while we add space in scanf method is goes to continue for scanning.

Answer (score 0):

The whitespace you have in `scanf()` ensures all whitespace chars are ignored (hence you hit ENTER, it's ignored). Hence, you had to input a non-whitespace character(s). See the [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) documentation. The solution is to remove the whitespace char from the scanf().

`scanf()` is notorious for input reading. So, you should consider using [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html) and then parse using `sscanf()`.

Also see: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

Comment: yes i got solution by removing whitespace in scanf() . Thank you.